# LogicApp make post in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-teams

Trying to make my LogicApp post in Microsoft Teams. At the moment I'm trying Team Id / Channel Id formatted as `19:[id-string]@thread.skype` with no success.

I get a `400`, bad request

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidRequest",
    "message": "groupId needs to be a valid GUID.\r\nParameter name: groupId",
```

If I copy the URL for the team and channel I see that they both share the same groupId, which I assume is the team GUID?

Tried with that as well but with a `403` instead. Not sure how to get the channel GUID.

`403`:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request PostMessageRequest.",
```

Any hints?

**Update** Team Id drop-down field displays

> "Could not retrieve values. User Login. Teams are disabled for your tenant."

[image]

Comment: Could you please try [Create Chat Thread](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/channel_post_chatthreads) API and let us know if it works?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Will need channel Id as a guid?

Comment: Please get Team Id using [List joinedTeams Api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_list_joinedteams) and Channel Id using [List channels Api](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/group_list_channels). You can try this using [Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Seems like my user is lacking some permissions, ie listing channels: Authorization has been denied for this request

Comment: How did you get the channel Id earlier? I could see some channel Id in the screenshot. Please try putting the same id and let us know.

Comment: I used my own account which works in Teams. But then I get a 403 with ---> code": "AccessDenied",
    "message": "Failed to execute Skype backend request PostMessageRequest.",

Comment: What endpoint are you trying to post to? This is not a bot, right?

Comment: @BillBliss-MSFT It's a logicapp that does the posting. As for now I can type in the teamId as a guid and for channel Id I can write anything. Same error, 403. I've read post where you can type in your "Team Name" as Id, a guid, or 19:[guid]@thread.skype. Nothing works

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT I think the problem is with the tenant, see my update. Not sure how to enable it

Comment: Please have a look at documentation on how to [Turn on Microsoft Teams for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Was related to Teams not activated for that tenant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at documentation on how to [Turn on Microsoft Teams for your organization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/get-started/get-started-tenant#turn-on-microsoft-teams-for-your-organization).

Note: Adding this as answer from comments.